# Python3. Как импортировать не весь модуль, а его переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как импортировать не весь модуль, а его переменную?
Написал так:

```
import modulname.variable
```

и так:

```
import modulname
modulname.variable
```

Но выводит полностью.
Как делать правильно?

Comment: Поясните, что "выводит полностью"?

Comment: @insolor кажется, вы забыли `import telepathy` :)

Answer (score 5):

В Питоне модули всегда целиком импортируются при успешном завершении `import` команды.

Обе формы: `import module` и `from module import name` импортируют модуль `module`. Разница в том что `from`-форма также добавляет имя `name` в текущее пространство имён.

Если `module.name` уже  существует (доступен как атрибут), то `from module import name` равнозначен:

```
import module
name = module.name
```

(за исключением введения `module` имени—сам модуль в обоих случаях загружен: можно в `sys.modules['module']` посмотреть).

Можно использовать обе формы, но если модуль не из стандартной библиотеки, то форма обращения `module.name` более предпочтительна—так как яснее откуда `name` берётся.

Если имя модуля часто встречается, то можно аббревиатуру для удобства использовать, например:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `from`
`from modulname import variable`
Так же можно использовать алиас для переменной
`from modulname import variable as var`

Answer (score 2):

С помощью `from`:

```
>>> from math import pi
>>> pi
3.141592653589793
>>>
```